# Node js api with front-end how to add book

Tags: node.js, api, frontend

I made an api with a database that stores books and I can get the book on the front-end like this

```
async function getBooks() {
  try {
     const response = await fetch("https://node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com/books");
    return await response.json();
    // console.log(books)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
  }
}

getBooks().then(book => {
   console.log(book);
});
```

But I want to figure at how to add a book to the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting this right and assuming that you configured you Api to accept Post requests then all you have to do is just send a post request to the backend API

```js
async function addBook(bookData) {
  try {
   const response = await fetch("https://node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com/books", {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
    body: JSON.stringify(bookData),
   });

    return response.json();
   } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
   }
}
```

and on the back end, you will parse the request with your middleware and then you can get the data from req.body

[resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data)

Comment: Thanks, it worked but when I added a long author and no title it gave me an application error on http://node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com/books do know why?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? 
it could be a few reasons like both of the `author` and the `title` are required fields on DB and maybe the author has some restriction on the number of author characters.
try it on the localhost or check the errors on Heroku logs

Comment: It is just giving me the heroku application error also I don't think it is required because I entered both author and title empty and it worked

Comment: it is hard to judge without having too much information, Heroku application error is usually 5xx server errors where  you are not handling the error the right way, it would be good if you can check the errors from the logs using `heroku logs --tail` or if you have the application locally then you can try and mimic the behavior and then check the errors on the terminal